# FOR r in (SELECT ... INTO ...)

Tags: oracle, plsql

Today, I came across a funny piece of code that I think should not compile. It uses an `SELECT ... INTO` clause within a `FOR r IN ... LOOP`. Here's a script that compiles on Oracle 11i. The script is a shortened version of actual PL/SQL code compiled in a package, runing in production.

```
create table tq84_foo (
   i number,
   t varchar2(10)
);

insert into tq84_foo values (1, 'abc');
insert into tq84_foo values (2, 'def');

declare

  rec tq84_foo%rowtype;

begin

  for r in (
     select     i,     t 
       into rec.i, rec.t -- Hmm???
       from tq84_foo
  )
  loop

    dbms_output.put_line('rec: i= ' || rec.i || ', t=' || rec.t);

  end loop;

end;
/


drop table tq84_foo purge;
```

The output, when run, is:

```
rec: i= , t=
rec: i= , t=
```

I *believe* 1) I can safely remove the `INTO` part of the `select` statement and 2) that this construct should either be invalid or exhibits at least undefined behaviour.

Are my two assumptions right?

Comment: THat is strange, esp when Oracle documentation explicitly mentions SQL select statement, not SELECT INTO for a cursor FOR loop http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

Comment: I've noticed that before but haven't found any references to it anywhere in the support docs. I'm pretty sure the `into` part is silently ignored - you can explicitly populate the `rec` fields and they aren't modified in or after the loop - and it's safe to removed; but citation needed, unfortunately...

Comment: And everything works perfectly if the `INTO` clause is removed, the values can be seen in output for `r.i and r.t` from the `for loop`. Which proves that the parser silently ignores. `DECLARE
  rec tq84_foo%rowTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN
  ( SELECT i, t 
  INTO rec.i, rec.t -- Hmm???
  FROM tq84_foo
  )
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line
    (
      'rec: i= ' || r.i || ', t=' || r.t
    )
    ;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
`   Really strange!

Comment: Docs explicitly says, `NOT PL/SQL SELECT INTO statement`, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1155

Comment: @LalitKumarB This should be reference enough to proof it is undefined behaviour and should not compile. According to the doc this is not allowed and might break after the next update, so get rid of it

Comment: As a reference, here is the link where I have posted the question based on the same issue. www.orafaq.com/forum/t/196022/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are partly right:

1) Yes, you can safely remove the `INTO` part of the `SELECT` statement. But you should change the line in the loop to this format:

```
dbms_output.put_line('rec: i= ' || r.i || ', t=' || r.t);
```

That way it will get the data out of the `r` variable

2) The problem with this code is that the syntax of the `SELECT ... INTO` should fail if the query return more than one row. If it does not fail so it might be a bug and will have unexpected behaviour.