# Pipeline table function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to understand why pipelined function is not returning any results
Any ideas what i am doing wrong here.

Giving credit where due to the Original Author

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MANAGE_SPACE AS
--Author Tanmay 
g_tblspce_threshold number := 80;
TYPE tblespaces_record IS RECORD(
       tablespace_name VARCHAR2(30), 
       percentage_used NUMBER
       );
TYPE tblespaces_table IS TABLE OF tblespaces_record;

function list_tblspcs_excd_thresld 
return tblespaces_table PIPELINED ;

END MANAGE_SPACE;
```

Package body

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MANAGE_SPACE
AS
  --Author Tanmay
  FUNCTION list_tblspcs_excd_thresld
    RETURN tblespaces_table PIPELINED
  AS
    tblspaces            tblespaces_record;
  BEGIN
   for x in (SELECT a.tablespace_name tablespace_name,
      ROUND (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES) * 100) percentage_used
      into tblspaces
    FROM dba_tablespaces a,
      (SELECT tablespace_name,
        SUM (BYTES) BYTES
      FROM dba_free_space
      GROUP BY tablespace_name
      ) b,
      (SELECT COUNT (1) DATAFILES,
        SUM (BYTES) BYTES,
        tablespace_name
      FROM dba_data_files
      GROUP BY tablespace_name
      ) c
    WHERE b.tablespace_name(+) = a.tablespace_name
    AND c.tablespace_name(+)   = a.tablespace_name
    AND ROUND (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES) * 100) > g_tblspce_threshold 
    ORDER BY NVL (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES), 0) DESC)
    loop
        PIPE ROW (tblspaces);
    end loop;
    return;
  END list_tblspcs_excd_thresld;
END MANAGE_SPACE;
```

executing this package does not return any rows

```
SQL> select * from table(MANAGE_SPACE.list_tblspcs_excd_thresld())
  2
SQL> /

TABLESPACE_NAME                PERCENTAGE_USED
------------------------------ ---------------
```

What am i doing wrong

Comment: Works for me. Does the inner query actually return something when you run it outside the package? Maybe you do not have any tablespaces that fulfill the criteria. And you should also get used to using explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the discouraged `(+)` operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to populate an array.  The easiest way to do this is to use the BULK COLLECT syntax.  Then loop round the array and pipe out rows.

Here is my revised version of your package.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MANAGE_SPACE
AS
  FUNCTION list_tblspcs_excd_thresld
    RETURN tblespaces_table PIPELINED
  AS
    -- collection type not record type
    tblspaces             tblespaces_table;
  BEGIN
   select * 
   -- populate the collection
   bulk collect  into tblspaces
   from
   (SELECT a.tablespace_name tablespace_name,
      ROUND (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES) * 100) percentage_used
    FROM dba_tablespaces a,
      (SELECT tablespace_name,
        SUM (BYTES) BYTES
      FROM dba_free_space
      GROUP BY tablespace_name
      ) b,
      (SELECT COUNT (1) DATAFILES,
        SUM (BYTES) BYTES,
        tablespace_name
      FROM dba_data_files
      GROUP BY tablespace_name
      ) c
    WHERE b.tablespace_name(+) = a.tablespace_name
    AND c.tablespace_name(+)   = a.tablespace_name
    AND ROUND (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES) * 100) > g_tblspce_threshold 
    ORDER BY NVL (((c.BYTES - NVL (b.BYTES, 0)) / c.BYTES), 0) DESC);
    -- loop round the collection
    for i in 1..tblspaces.count()
    loop
        PIPE ROW (tblspaces(i));
    end loop;
    return;
  END list_tblspcs_excd_thresld;
END MANAGE_SPACE;
```

Here is the output:

```
SQL> select * from table(MANAGE_SPACE.list_tblspcs_excd_thresld())
  2  /

TABLESPACE_NAME                PERCENTAGE_USED
------------------------------ ---------------
SYSTEM                                     100
SYSAUX                                      91
APEX_2614203650434107                       90
EXAMPLE                                     87
USERS                                       82

SQL>
```

---

@a_horse_with_no_name makes a good point regarding memory consumption.  Collections are held in the session's memory space, the PGA.  In this particular case it is unlikely that a database would have enough tablespaces to blow the PGA limit.  But for other queries which might have much larger result sets there is the BULK COLLECT ... LIMIT syntax, which allows us to fetch manageable chunks of the result set into our collection.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BABJIAFH).

Comment: The original code works for me (although I was surprised that you can use a `select ... into` inside a `for` loop)

Comment: Hi APC Thanks a ton for the solution.Every time i compile this i get an error saying ORA-04068: existing state of packages has been discarded
ORA-04061: existing state of package body "SYSTEM.MANAGE_SPACE" has been
invalidated
ORA-04065: not executed, altered or dropped package body "SYSTEM.MANAGE_SPACE"

Comment: Hi Horse not sure though why it doesn't work for me i am on 12c

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - on my 11gR2 rig I got five empty rows.

Comment: @jhon.smith: works for me in 11g, but in 12c the `into` clause does not seem to work actually. I usually try to avoid bulk collect because of the potential memory requirements - but I guess the result of that query is never going to be a memory problem. An alternate solution is to remove the `into` clause and explicitly assign values before the `pipe row()` call:  `tblspaces.tablespace_name := x.tablespace_name; tblspaces.percentage_used := x.percentage_used;`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There was a question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27899660/for-r-in-select-into