# Select Into in PL/SQL cursor. What does it do?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a mistake in my code due to a copy paste error and am curious why it compiles, and precisely what does it do?

```
MT_REC MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
MT_OUT_REC MY_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
CURSOR CHECK_MT
IS
  SELECT *
  INTO MT_OUT_REC
  FROM MY_TABLE MT
  WHERE MT.CLAIMS_PATIENT_ID = MT_REC.CLAIMS_PATIENT_ID OR
        MT.PATH_PATIENT_ID = MT_REC.PATH_PATIENT_ID;

Begin
  FOR MT_OUT_REC IN CHECK_MT
  LOOP
  -- DO STUFF
  END LOOP;
End;
```

The part I feel is invalid syntax is the "INTO" clause in a cursor definition.

I will be removing this clause, but I was just curious why it compiles and what it does.

Edit:

The "Duplicate" question is in fact similar, but since it seems to not have been answered, I think this somewhat different question should remain, in case new eyes may have more relevant information.

Comment: [This has come up before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27899660/266304), but without much in the way of a real answer. It does nothing, and is ignored, but probably safer to remove it in case the behaviour changes in the future.

Comment: I did search for this, but missed the link you provided. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: However it is not precisely the same, and if you flagged it as duplicate, please remove it.